# How to get better video quality in Lync?

Tags: video, streaming, webcam, qos, lync-2013

I want to use a ConferenceCam from Logitech to stream talks live via Lync. When I view the RAW webcam image via VLC, the quality is very good (but the latency is high because of buffering). However, when I stream it using Lync, the video gets blurry.

Is there a way to ensure QoS in Lync or otherwise improve the video quality to (near-)native? I would rather have some dropped frames than a lower resolution where I can't read the slides.

In my setup, I use Lync with an Office365-E3 contract, so I have no Lync-Server in my network. I thought about replacing Lync completely with VLC, but I first want to try Lync because VLC will probably cause firewall issues. Also, I haven't looked up the VLC parameters for less buffering, faster encoding, a bit lower resolution (natively it's more than HD) and streaming.

Comment: There likely isn't a way to increase the quality.  Out of curosity do you experience the same problems with Skype?  ( Don't worry the Skype is just a test ).

Comment: Lync does QOS AFAIK but I doubt that it survives your router anyway. The fact that you have buffering problems when viewing HQ video probably should tell you that your PC can't cope with it. Check out the PC first. There shouldn't be any problems with Lync on O365, I use that sometimes too.

Comment: @JulianKnight Are there guidelines on computer hardware for realtime fullhd-encoding and broadcasting for lync? I only found this: http://blog.schertz.name/2011/10/hd-video-in-lync/ I never thought this is an issue today. The hardware is dell latitude e6520 with core i5-cpu and 8gb ram.

Comment: Urm, not a simple question! A Raspberry PI can handle HQ video streams because of its embedded Broadcom chipset, to do it using raw CPU power needs something pretty healthy such as a decent i5 CPU. In otherwords, it depends. Depends on the PC hardware configuration and the drivers. I wouldn't expect a consumer grade 3yr old laptop to do it for example but I would expect a 2yr old business grade laptop to - if only from certain suppliers such as Lenovo. Does your Latitude have a decent graphics card?

Comment: @JulianKnight Intel HD Graphics from 2010 in 45nm, no idea what generation this is.
According to this: http://blog.schertz.name/2013/05/hd-video-lync-2013/ I looked up in dxdiag and found no DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_NoFGT in there, this means encoding in lync isn't hardware accelerated. I also have a VideoEncodeScore in my '%Windir%\Performance\WinSAT\DataStore' of 6.9. If I match this against the second table here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj688132.aspx I found out that I can only encode 640x360 while I can decode 1920x1080. So I need better graphics hardware.

Comment: OK, I think you've answered your own question :( 2010 & yes, you need better graphics hardware I'm afraid, the embedded Intel graphics from that era simply isn't anywhere near good enough to handle HD streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restraining criteria to video quality for me was the hardware capabilities of the laptop which I used. This is how to determine the maximum resolution of video encoding your hardware is capable of:

The following answer is mostly based on this much longer blog post: http://blog.schertz.name/2013/05/hd-video-lync-2013/

- Check whether the graphics chip in use has hardware accelerated video encoding. For Intel chips, it must say something like "Quick Sync Video" on [ark.intel.com](http://ark.intel.com/). Also note the number of cores of your CPU. For AMD, check the source-link above.
- Check, whether your hardware supports DXVA. For this, press Windows+R and enter `dxdiag`. Click "save all information..." to save everything to a file. Open the file and search for `DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_NoFGT`. If you find it, you have DXVA.
- Check your `VideoEncodeScore`. Search for this term in the file `%Windir%\Performance\ WinSAT\DataStore\*Formal.Assesment*` (There can be a number of files like this in that folder, open the most recent.) The score is a decimal number. Search in the same file for `GraphicsScore`. Also note this number.
- Now go to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj688132.aspx and check which maximum video encoding resolution applies to your spec.

There is also the chance you have a camera that supports HD 1080p H.264/SVC UVC 1.5 encoding. Currently, it seems only this one does so: http://www.logitech.com/assets/47868/logitech-webcam-c930e-data-sheet.pdf